# 'this' in Java: How does it work?

Tags: java

I know that 'this' is acting as reference in Java.  We can use it inside the class members only.

What I am asking is... because it is used in the members of the class, that means it has to be either an instance variable or parameter.

And assume, if it is param to a method but it is working in blocks.  block does not contain any params and all ..could you explain what is it ...how exactly it was defined in java?How exactly it is using By JVM.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What's this about parameter and working in blocks?

Comment: I tried to translate this, I have edited it up to the last paragraph.  Perhaps someone who understands it can try to translate it.

Comment: could you give code examples?

Answer (score 32):

From a linguistic point of view, `this` is neither a local variable or a parameter.  Syntactically, it is a keyword.  Semantically, it is an explicit way of saying "the current object"; see [JLS 15.8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.3).  For example:

- `this.<attributeName>` explicitly refers to an instance level attribute of the current object.
- `<methodName>(this)` calls a method, passing a reference to the current object as an explicit argument.

The `this` keyword has other uses in Java that don't exactly mean "the current object":

- `this(<optArgumentList>)` as the first statement in a constructor chains to another constructor in the same class; [JLS 8.8.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.7.1).
- `<className>.this` within an inner class refers to the instance of an enclosing class for the current object; [JLS 15.8.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4).

---

From an implementation perspective, you can think of the "this" reference as a hidden or implicit parameter that gets passed each time an instance method is called.  Indeed, this is more or less how the object reference is treated by the JVM's "invoke*" bytecodes.  You push the target object reference onto the "opstack" followed by each of the argument values, then execute the "invoke..." instruction.  (Look [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html#invokeinterface) for the details.).

Comment: @polygenelubricants - I borrowed your references.  Thanks.

Comment: While this answer is correct, you consider also to look on another comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/3413324/1137529 here for some "lightweight" answer.

Comment: @alexsmail - yes it is a simpler answer.  But that simplicity comes from saying things that are not strictly meaningful from a linguistic standpoint.  And it assumes a specific implementation model.  And it is only simple if the reader grasps the way that computers work at the instruction level.

Comment: @alexsmail, if you wanna be technical most impl. keep 'this' in ECX/RCX register on x86 avoiding actually putting it on the stack (when the code is compiled and not interpreted)

Answer (score 7):

Instance methods are invoked within the context of an actual instance, an actual object.

Within the instance method of a `class`, `this` (in most context) refers to this object. This is a *relative* reference: when the same method is invoked on another object, then `this` within the execution of that method now refers to this second object.

For completeness, it should be mentioned that Java also has what is called "qualified" `this` that can be used to refer to not the object that the method is invoked upon, but the *enclosing* object of an inner `class`.

It can also appear, with some restriction, in constructors, to invoke another constructor of the same class. `super` can also be used in this manner.

#### References

- [JLS 15.8.3 `this`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.3)

  - When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked, or to the object being constructed.
- [JLS 15.8.4 Qualified `this`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4)

  - Any lexically enclosing instance can be referred to by explicitly qualifying the keyword `this`.
- [JLS 8.8.7.1 Explicit Constructor Invocations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.7.1)

  - *Alternate constructor invocations* begin with the keyword `this` (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.

Answer (score 6):

> How exactly was [this] defined in Java?

In Java `this` is defined by the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) as a [keyword](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#229308) and therefore is not an ordinary variable name and has special behaviour.

The behaviour of `this` is defined in [section 15.8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.3) of the specification. For example:

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value, that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

Answer (score 5):

"this" is implicitly passed as argument for every non-static method call you make. You can think of it as syntactical sugar, but at machine level, it is indeed an additional parameter which gets passed.

```
class Person
{
  string name;
  int age;
  void print(){ System.out.writeln(name+" "+age); }
}
```

works like that (pseudo-code):

```
class Person
{
  string name;
  int age;
}

void print(Person this)
{
  System.out.writeln(this.name+" "+this.age);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of thinking about it is as an implicit parameter to instance methods and constructors. In the case of a constructor it's the job of the constructor to set up "this", while in the case of instance methods, they can operate on "this" as appropriate.

Note that Java also has some syntactic sugar allowing you to implicitly reference fields and methods of "this" without specifying `this.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` will give you a reference to the actual instance. It's very common in constructors, eg:

```
class Dog {
   String name;

   public Dog(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Comment: The main purpose in constructor is to avoid shadow variables. In your example, the compiler doesn't know which variable named `name`, so `this.name` is for the instance variable and the `name` is for the parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of 'this' refer to itself. It's like me.[attribute] to access itself attributes or methods.